# How do I give moviepy access to custom installed fonts on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, imagemagick, moviepy

I have been looking through the depths of the internet and still cannot find anything. When I execute

```
print(TextClip.list("font"))
```

My custom-installed fonts are not available. After some research, I thought it could be possible that it has to do with ImageMagick not recognizing my installed fonts. When I researched that, most documentation is for Mac/Linux because Windows supposedly allows all applications to use installed fonts, so ImageMagick should just recognize it.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

I exptected

```
clip = TextClip("text", color='black', font='PKMN RBYGSC Regular',
                   fontsize=32, )
```

to use my installed font "PKMN RBYGSC Regular". I have tried all iterations of the name, such as:
'PKMN-RBYGSC-Regular', 'PKMN_RBYGSC_Regular', r'C:\Windows\Fonts\PKMN_RBYGSC.ttf', etc.

The result was moviepy using the default font. I read that this has to do with ImageMagick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You have to do this with ImageMagicK. On windows, go to ImageMagicK installation folder and find the type-ghostscript.xml file.

Simply add the custom font in the  tag. For example, if you want to add Poppins font then you have to use

```
<type name="Poppins" fullname="Poppins" family="Poppins" style="normal" weight="400" stretch="normal" format="type1" metrics="C:\Users\Downloads\Poppins\Poppins-Regular.ttf" glyphs="C:\Users\Downloads\Poppins\Poppins-Regular.ttf" />
```

Save this file as administrator.

Then, do this

```
clip = TextClip("text", color='black', font='Poppins',
                   fontsize=32)
```

Comment: How to add font to a Linux system?